# How to switch index in PyQt5's QStackedLayout using a QPushButton - why doesn't my MVC controller work?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm currently learning PyQt5 and am struggling with how to use a `QStackedLayout` - in particular how to set the current index of the stacked layout via a button press using the signals and slots model.

Here's a minimal example showing my issue.

```
import sys  # used to handle application exit

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStackedLayout, QVBoxLayout


# GUI
class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(1024, 600)
        # central widget
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        # general layout
        self._generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self._generalLayout)
        # ui elements
        self._createHeader()
        self._createMainScreen()

    def _createHeader(self):
        """Create the GUI's header"""
        self.switchscreenbutton = QPushButton()
        self.switchscreenbutton.setText("SWITCH")
        self._generalLayout.addWidget(self.switchscreenbutton)

    def _createMainScreen(self):
        """Create the GUI's control screen"""
        self.screens = []
        self.screenslayout = QStackedLayout()

        self._createControlScreen(self.screenslayout)
        self._createSettingsScreen(self.screenslayout)

        self._generalLayout.addLayout(self.screenslayout)

    def _createControlScreen(self, container):
        templabel = QLabel()
        templabel.setText("CONTROL")
        container.addWidget(templabel)

    def _createSettingsScreen(self, container):
        templabel = QLabel()
        templabel.setText("SETTINGS")
        container.addWidget(templabel)


# CONTROLLER
class Control:
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        self._model = model
        self._view = view
        # connect signals and slots (MVC framework used by PyQt5)
        self._connectSignals()

    def _connectSignals(self):
        self._view.switchscreenbutton.clicked.connect(self._switchscreen)

    def _switchscreen(self):
        if self._view.screenslayout.currentIndex() == 1:
            self._view.screenslayout.setCurrentIndex(0)
        else:
            self._view.screenslayout.setCurrentIndex(1)


# Client code
def main():
    """Main function"""
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # show GUI
    gui = UI()
    gui.show()
    # model and controller
    model = None    # TODO
    Control(model=model, view=gui)
    # execute event loop
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To summarise, I have a push button above a stacked layout. The stacked layout displays a different label depending on the current index of the layout. On click of the push button, `Control`'s `_switchscreen()` method is called (this is set up in `Control`'s `_connectSignals()`, which should set the current index of the layout accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Control object is not assigned to a variable then it will be destroyed so its methods will not work. The solution is:

```
control = Control(model=model, view=gui)
```

Comment: Oh that's an embarrassing ommission. Thanks for catching it!